# What would happen to a person with no identity?

Tags: criminal-law, immigration

I'm working on an RPG, and a few of the characters have no ID, and are secretly from another universe.

If one is processed for a minor crime (say, trespassing), but has no ID, no history, and no citizenship anywhere, what would happen to them?

The perp knows he's from another dimension. Admitting it will surely result in an asylum, but what about just pretending to be a native, though nothing is verifiable?
To clarify, these people have no relatives that know them, they have IDs that come up as fake/fraudulent, and no link to any country whatsoever.

Also, for jurisdiction, its California, but the FBI is also involved.

Comment: No identity is not the same as no identity documents.

Comment: I can't see how this question is on-topic for this site. At the very least you would need to specify the jurisdiction. Probably it should be migrated to [worldbuilding.se].

Comment: This question is most probably on-topic for [worldbuilding.se], if you would like it migrated there, please flag. However, this question is on-topic here; you're likely to get answers for a selection of jurisdictions if you don't specify one.

Comment: Here is what I don't understand. In the last paragraph we get information that the person is from another dimension. Then the editorial comment about *asylum surely being granted*. But then we are asked to ignore those facts and assume the authorities treat the person as native? So we are really just dealing with a person with no id? Furthermore, what do you mean by native? Native to the country where the crime is charged? Or native earthling?

Comment: Apologies. I did not mean asylum as an immigrant gaining a residential status. I meant a mental health facility.

Comment: As mentioned world building would be the best to ask questions like this. Questions should always be in the realms of possibility on this stack.

Comment: @Terry Disagree. The impossible thing in this question is a framing device; it is certainly possible for a real person to end up with no ID or identifiable link to any country.

Comment: I ran a scenario a few years ago that got here with none of the alien business (it mainly involved destroyed identity papers). Basically, the question is on-topic even if the setup is not.

Answer (score 1):

Processing creates an "identity."  Not that it would serve the alien for any positive purposes, but his fingerprints, photograph, physical description, and whatever name/alias he provided would be in a national database should any law enforcement agency come across him in the future.

But after being processed, if it's for a minor crime, he will probably be released, perhaps after being required to post a small bail to ensure his appearance for arraignment.

Answer (score 0):

Someone may remember details, but there is an ongoing real world case where a man was found in the USA without any documents and with memory loss, who was and is assumed to be a US citizen (because there is no reason to believe otherwise) with unknown identity. He has been absolutely unable to get identity papers, social security number, and therefore any official job. There is a very detailed discussion on wikipedia - I hope someone knows a name.

Summary: Your alien is stuck in a major way.

Comment: Benjamin Kyle? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjaman_Kyle